# How to convert bool to string in a C# model instead of the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Typically, if I have a bool field in my model, it is because the underlying database has a bit value. My users, however, would prefer to have yes/no instead of true/false or checkbox in views. Typically, I convert bool to string in my view model.

I was wondering if it were possible to do that conversion in the data model instead of the controller, which I had learned how to do a few years back. I've done some research and tried converting the original field from this:

```
public bool StudentInRoster { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
private bool? _studentInRoster;
public string StudentInRoster => _studentInRoster == true ? "Yes" : "No";
```

However, ReSharper gives me a warning:

> "field _studentInRoster" is never assigned"

So I figure something is still not right. Is there a better (i.e., correct) way to do this type of conversion? I will need to save data as bool but present the data as yes/no.

Comment: Is `_studentInRoster` actually assigned a value anywhere?

Comment: It's whatever the database values are. Entity Framework handles that.

Comment: You can use a display template to format the way your property is displayed. I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a display template to show your property with your desired result instead. I think this is the best approach.

Create a `DisplayTemplates` folder under Shared folder an add a partial view to it and name it something for example (`_myTemplate`) and then paste the following code to it:

```
@model bool
@if (Model)
{
    @Html.Encode("Yes")
}
@if (Model == false)
{
    @Html.Encode("No")
}
```

Then you can add data annotation by using [`UIHintAttribute.UIHint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint(v=vs.110).aspx) to your property to use this display template.

```
[UIHint("_myTemplate")]
public bool StudentInRoster { get; set; }
```

Then in your `View`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.StudentInRoster)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's bad idea to do this in data model. 
ViewModel is one **right** place for this.

1. Data model is responsible for "how data is stored (as bit column)"
2. ViewModel is responsible to prepare data for display (as strings/images/video and so on)

Comment: "ViewModel is responsible for display data" - let's rephrase this as "ViewModel is responsible to prepare data for display".

Answer (score 0):

```
@model bool
@if (Model)`{
@Html.Encode("Yes")
}

@if (Model == false)
{


 @Html.Encode("No")
}

[UIHint("_myTemplate")]
public bool StudentInRoster { get; set; }

@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.StudentInRoster)
```